# How should I do to transfer different classes by tcp without implementing a type of message per each class?

Tags: c#, tcp

I need to transfer by TCP (with networkcomms) different elements(like spheres, cubes, clamp, dimplejacket...) from my server to my client.

on your opinion, what would be the best way to send messages containing the datas(i mean radius, length, height...) of thoses classes without having to implement as many class of messages as there are classes of elements ?

because currently when i send a message, i send a message of type "Communicate" (which is my class that i send as a message)
i dont want to have classes CommunicateSphere, CommunicateCube... but rather a class CommunicateElement that would be able to communicate all thoses datas properly

i imagined transferring an "Object" type but obviously "Object doesn't contain a definition for GetPrimitiveType()

```cs
        /// <summary>
        /// Performs whatever functions we might so desire when we receive an incoming ChatMessage
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="header">The PacketHeader corresponding with the received object</param>
        /// <param name="connection">The Connection from which this object was received</param>
        /// <param name="incomingMessage">The incoming CommunicateElement we are after</param>
    private void HandleIncomingObject(PacketHeader header, Connection connection, CommunicateElement incomingMessage)
    {



        PrimitiveType type = incomingMessage.Message.GetPrimitiveType();
        GameObject go = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(type);

    }
```

at the end, i'm supposed to have buttons (or whatever graphic element) that would send messages to unity (containing the datas of an element) in order to create the specified element

Comment: Serialize them as Json?

Comment: If you don't want the code to serialise/deserialise/process the elements you are sending on the client then you need to do complicated things with dynamic compilation and sending source code from your server. Are you sure that's what you want to do?

Comment: i didn't know what serializing/deserializing was, now i know, and it is exactly what i need, many thanks